# discord.js how to find role by name

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a sipmle registration function, but I can't figure out what is the problem. This is the code:

```
fasz.on('messageReactionAdd', async (msg, guild,  reaction, user) =>{
    let registered = msg.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Regisztrált");
    if(reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
    if(reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
    if(user.bot) return;
    if(!reaction.message.guild) return;
    if(reaction.message.channel.id === '718990681745522728'){
        if(reaction.emoji.name === ''){
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(registered)
            return user.send('Sikeres regisztráció! Üdvözlünk a szerveren!')

        }
    }
})
```

And this is the error message is get:

```
C:\Users\god\Documents\GitHub\discord.js\main.js:74
    let registered = msg.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Regisztrált");
                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\god\Documents\GitHub\discord.js\main.js:74:32)
    at Client.emit (node:events:376:20)
    at MessageReactionAdd.handle (C:\Users\god\Documents\GitHub\discord.js\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageReactionAdd.js:49:17)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD] (C:\Users\god\Documents\GitHub\discord.js\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD.js:4:37)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\god\Documents\GitHub\discord.js\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\god\Documents\GitHub\discord.js\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\god\Documents\GitHub\discord.js\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\god\Documents\GitHub\discord.js\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:376:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\god\Documents\GitHub\discord.js\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:835:20)
```

Comment: Instead of `msg.guild.roles.find()` you should just directly try using `guild.roles.find()`.

Comment: now i get this error message, I tried get, and fetch instead find, but none of them works.

    let registered = guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Regisztrált");
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Comment: After doing a little bit of investigation, I found out that `Client#messageReactionAdd` event only emits a `MessageReaction` and a `user`. That means you can't pass four variables into your function, only two.

Answer (score 2):

Like I mentioned in the comment, the `Client#messageReactionAdd` event only emits two variables. That means you cannot arbitrarily use four variables to your liking to assign it.

Code:

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => { //basically changed four to two variables
    //replaced msg.guild.roles.find() with reaction.message.guild.roles.find()
    let registered = reaction.message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Regisztrált");
    if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
    if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
    if (user.bot) return;
    if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
    if (reaction.message.channel.id === '718990681745522728') {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(registered)
            return user.send('Sikeres regisztráció! Üdvözlünk a szerveren!')
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get a `role` by it's name like this:

```js
const role = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Yor role name');
```

After getting the `role` you can get the `user` and assign the `role`:

```js
const { guild } = reaction.message

const member = guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id);

member.roles.add(role);
```

Comment: Not only is `message` not defined, but you're required to use `cache` to get the cached roles collection of a guild.

Comment: @ItamarS Jup, sorry. I updated the answer